# mpv crash in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.10

mpv crashes. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
$ mpv --hwdec=auto file.mp4 
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (av1 2560x1440 60.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (aac 2ch 44100Hz)
[vo/gpu/wayland] GNOME's wayland compositor lacks support for the idle inhibit protocol. This means the screen can blank during playback.
[ffmpeg] AVHWDeviceContext: Failed to query surface attributes: 20 (the requested function is not implemented).
[vo/gpu/vaapi-egl] failed to retrieve libavutil frame constraints
[ffmpeg/video] av1: Failed to end picture decode issue: 23 (internal decoding error).
[ffmpeg/video] av1: HW accel end frame fail.
Error while decoding frame (hardware decoding)!
[ffmpeg/video] av1: Failed to end picture decode issue: 23 (internal decoding error).
[ffmpeg/video] av1: HW accel end frame fail.
Error while decoding frame (hardware decoding)!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

```
$ mpv --version
mpv 0.34.1 Copyright © 2000-2021 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
 built on UNKNOWN
FFmpeg library versions:
   libavutil       57.17.100 (runtime 57.28.100)
   libavcodec      59.18.100 (runtime 59.37.100)
   libavformat     59.16.100 (runtime 59.27.100)
   libswscale      6.4.100 (runtime 6.7.100)
   libavfilter     8.24.100 (runtime 8.44.100)
   libswresample   4.3.100 (runtime 4.7.100)
FFmpeg version: 5.1.1-1ubuntu1
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux Ubuntu-7610 5.19.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 23 20:44:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 1.15.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.15 (libva 2.12.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 22.4.3 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointStats
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain12             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileAV1Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it.

```
$ sudo apt install intel-media-va-driver-non-free
```

The above will REMOVE `intel-media-va-driver`